Minkowski sum between an open bounded set and the unit ball
Given an open bounded set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $x\in \partial U$. I'm having difficulty checking whether
$$
\overline{B}(x,1)\cap \partial(U+\overline{B})\neq \emptyset, \quad \quad (1)
$$
where $\overline{B}(x,1)$ and $\overline{B}$ denote the closed balls with radius $1$ centered at $x$ and $0$, respectively, and $U+\overline{B}$ is the usual Minkowski sum.
It seems to me the answer is positive for any open bounded set $U$. I tried with some examples, including the ones where $\partial U$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$, or Lipschitz, but they all satisfy $(1)$.
Any help is appreciated!

Let $U=(-1,0) \cup (0,1), x=0$. Then $U+\bar{B} =(-2,2)$ and so the result is false in general.

@copper.hat Very nice example. Thank you! By the way, what is your thought when $U$ is also convex?
